# How to avoid making a double call to the service in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

The code makes a call to the API that will get me the races of a track through an event that captures its TrackID and gets the respective races of that track, but I need that data to persist, since when I click on the track more than once calls again in the service which is not optimal.

```
**Method with API call API**

raceTrackRequest(data){

        this.getConfiguration();
        const url = this.baseURL + 'BusRace/GetRacesTrack';

        const requestJSON = {
            DGSReq: {
                InParams: {
                    LogonSessionID: 1,
                    ProfileID: 1,
                    TrackID: data.id,
                    RaceDate: this.actualDate
                }
            }
        };

        axios.post(url, requestJSON)
            .then((response) => {
                AppDispatcher.dispatch({
                    type: ActionTypes.GET_RACE_TRACK,
                    data: {...response.data.DGSResp, ...{TrackID: data.id}}
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

**Store **

    getInitialState() {
        return {  
            racesTrack: {
                Races: []
            }
        };
    }

    reduce(state, action) {
        let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
        switch (action.type) {
            case ActionTypes.GET_RACE_TRACK:
                newState.selectedOptions.track = action.data.TrackID;
                newState.racesTrack = action.data;
                break;
            default:
                newState = state;
        }
        return newState;
    }

**Component**

    static getStores() {
        return [ConfigStore, PlayerStore];
    };

    static calculateState() {
        const data = ConfigStore.getState();
        return {
            data: data
        };
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        let params = {...this.state, ...{actionType: ActionTypes.LOAD_CONFIG}};
        ActionCreators.actionTrigger(params);
    }

    handleClick(actionType, id, name, post, distance, purse, surface, trackcond, WagerTypes, entry) {
        const params = {
            actionType: actionType,
            id: id,
            name,
            post: post,
            distance: distance,
            purse: purse,
            surface: surface,
            trackcond: trackcond,
            WagerTypes: WagerTypes,
            entry: entry

        };

        ActionCreators.actionTrigger(params);
        this.setState ({
            raceID: id,
            name,
            post: post,
            distance: distance,
            purse: purse,
            surface: surface,
            trackcond: trackcond,
            WagerTypes: WagerTypes,
            render: entry

        });

    };


    render() {
        const races = this.state.data.racesTrack.Races;
        const racesList = [];

        if(races){
            races.forEach((race) => {
                racesList.push(
                    <span className="badge" style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} key={race['race-id']} onClick={() =>
                this.handleClick(ActionTypes.GET_RACE_ENTRIES,
                                race['race-id'],
                                race['race-desc'],
                                race['post-time'],
                                race['distance'],
                                race['purse'],
                                race['surface'],
                                race['trackCond'],
                                race['WagerTypes']
                                )}>{race['race-number']}
                </span>
                );
            });
        }

        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

**Component tracks who calls racesTrack**

class TracksBar extends Component {

    static getStores() {
        return [ConfigStore];
    };

    static calculateState() {
        const configData = ConfigStore.getState();
        return {
            configInfo: configData
        };

    };

    handleClick(actionType, id) {
        const params = {actionType: actionType, id: id};
        ActionCreators.actionTrigger(params);
    };

    render() {

        const showTracks = this.state.configInfo.tracks.TrackList;
        const tracklist = [];
        const harnessList = [];
        const greyList = [];

        if(showTracks){
            showTracks.forEach((track) => {
                if(track['track-type'] === 0) {
                    tracklist.push(
                        <tr key={track['track-id']} onClick={() => this.handleClick(ActionTypes.GET_RACE_TRACK,track['track-id'])}>
                            <td className="col-sm-6"><Link to="/races">{track['track-name']}</Link></td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                } else if(track['track-type'] === 1) {
                    harnessList.push(
                        <tr key={track['track-id']} onClick={() => this.handleClick(ActionTypes.GET_RACE_TRACK,track['track-id'])}>
                            <td className="col-sm-6"><Link to="/races">{track['track-name']}</Link></td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                } else if(track['track-type'] === 2) {
                    greyList.push(
                        <tr key={track['track-id']} onClick={() => this.handleClick(ActionTypes.GET_RACE_TRACK,track['track-id'])}>
                            <td className="col-sm-6"><Link to="/races">{track['track-name']}</Link></td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                }
            });
        }

        else{
            console.log('no hay tracks')
        }

        return (
            <div className={styles.main}>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Is there any way to put that object that returns the service in an array so that when you click it again go to that array and check if that data already exists so that it does not call the service again?

Comment: If you're looking to store data in react-redux, the redux store is a pretty good place.

Comment: I know but, I'm newbie in react and I don't know exactly how to do it

Comment: You're asking a really broad question, please try to do some research first, for example going through the [official introduction](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started). If you're going to be using Redux, you'll have to educate yourself on how it works.

Comment: Also search for the terms caching and memoization.